# Is it guaranteed that all the WPF bindings will be functional when OnStartup() is called?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I am working on an application that uses WPF/C# with MVVM. I have one particular `ObservableCollection<>` which is bound to `ListBox`.

**Scenario 1**: When the application is running, I modify this `ObservableCollection<>` and `ListBox` is populated as expected.

**Scenario 2**: With new requirements I have to fill this ListBox by default with some init values. So I have added a method for initializing it in my ViewModel. I call this method in OnStartup() after initializing View & ViewModel. DataContext is also set properly. In this scenario values are updated in the ObservableCollection<>, Unfortunately they are not reflected in the ListBox.

Just to verify if anything is wrong with the OnStartup(), I added the same method call in a callback on ContentRendered from the View, instead of OnStartup() it did work fine.

So my question, **When exactly MVVM guarantees that all the bindings are setup correctly?**

**Edit:**
One more observation, if I pop a message/dialog ListBox is populated as expected. It calls ContentRendered callback. And then it populates correctly.

I am almost convinced that ContentRendered should be the function that guarantees the bindings.

Answer (score 3):

I can't say with certainty that this is your issue, without seeing the change to the code, but it sounds like you may now have an initial value of `null` for the property to which you are binding.

If you subsequently set that property to an `ObservableCollection<T>`, there is no automatic change notification.

One option would be to raise a notification that the property value changed (from `null` to something), and then let the `ObservableCollection<T>` handle change notification from there.

The better solution would be to initialize the property with an empty `ObservableCollection<T>` from the get-go, then your initialization to default values will mean adding those values and change notification should happen as you expect.

You might get the same problem by starting with a non-null collection, then setting the property to a new instance of a collection, without raising a notification, but I'm not 100 percent certain of that.

If this is not your issue, then I'll be happy to take another look.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the property is already initialized with an empty `ObservableCollection<T>`. The problem I am trying to understand is the same thing works fine in regular use case, its just the starting point. I have edited and added some more details.